# Updating PHP mySQL drivers when updating mySQL

Tags: mysql, php, drivers

I have apache, php, and mysql all installed from source. When I update mySQL to the latest version (5.1.46), do I need to update anything on the php side for it to be able to work with the new version?

Many Thanks

Edit: I'm updating from 5.1.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I upgraded MySQL and restarted apache, and it all appears to be working. The new version numbers show up in phpinfo() so it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Which_PHP_Driver_for_MySQL_should_I_use

See what versions you have by running phpinfo();

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. What I mean, is that the 'Client API Version' in PDO, mysql and mysql in phpinfo currently say 5.1.45. When I update to the latest version of mysql, do these need updating as well, or will they update automatically?

Comment: The PDO docs say "PDO_MYSQL is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface  to enable access from PHP to MySQL 3.x, 4.x and 5.x databases." So i don't see why they'd stop working on a minor version upgrade of mysql. phpinfo() should tell if the drivers are loaded or not.